# Why is it important to have more than one person creating a game?

Tags: game-design

Why is it important to have more than one person creating a game?

Comment: What data do you have to back that statement? There are plenty of examples of games that have been successful and have been developed by a single person.

Comment: Answer: it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the scope of your game it comes down to what makes up for the final product.

You have

Mechanic/Gamelogic programmers
Engine programmers (in house development)
AI programmer
Concept artists
3D Artists
2D Artists
Music composers
Animators
game designers
narrative designers/writers
sound designers
tech & VFX artists
tools programmers
quality control
localisation
producers & project managers
Let's not forget the voice actors
Eh legal team too?

And then you probably have branches within those disciplines as well.

Unless you master all these skills and are super efficient at it, you don't need anyone else. But that's hardly the case. And if you take it upon yourself to do everything it will just take more time and effort.

If it's a small indie game that looks super simple you're probably fine on your own.

A medium sized game can be done by a small team.

For big games you have to consider all the additional people such as managers, marketing etc as well.

If you're using a full fledged engine many things are simplified for you. However you're still bound to creating each individual part ( art, music, code?).

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a need for having more than one person creating a game because of there are three main tasks:

Art
Music
Programming

Which are so different between them.

Also as @Sidar said you could need marketing people to help you too.